# ASP.NET page or control marked as internal doesn't work and gives "inaccessible due to its protection level" error

Tags: asp.net

I know why this happens and I want to find a workaround it.

Example: a user control that exist in 2 assemblies, loaded at the same time.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
    }
}
```

My situation - I want to be able to share **user interface control** between two web applications which are loaded at the **same time** in the **same application pool**. If my user interface class is marked `public`, then ASP.NET will not like it because it will be duplicated into memory ( CLR uses namespaces as full qualifier for class, and if the same class and namespace is met it more than one assembly, exception is thrown ). I do then mark the class as internal and of course I forget how UI compilation occurs, and I expect it to work. Of course it doesn't because ASP.NET compiles the UI into separate assembly which is dynamic and since I marked the class as internal, it is not visible to the main assembly...

The question that follows is: How can I make dynamic compiled assemblies that ASP.NET generates to view the main application assembly internals? It is very unfortunate that classes and methods I write into my UI controls must always be public! Has anyone met this obstacle in his daily work and found a workaround?

EDIT:

Precompilation is not possible here due to other circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share User Control markup between apps using a Virtual Path Provider (see
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/27/431650.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx).

You can pull the markup for the control from anywhere - SharePoint uses VPP to get markup from the database, and I use it in some projects to pull from a non-standard location on disk (which is shared between projects).

Answer (score 0):

If your base class is internal, the derived class that ASP.NET generates at runtime will not be able to extend it.

However, I don't understand the issue that you're running into in the first place.  Two distinct web applications will always run in different AppDomains (even if they're in the same app pool), and there should be no type conflicts between the AppDomains.

I probably need more details about what you are doing.  e.g. what assembly are you compiling your base class into, and why does it end up in two different assemblies?

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. However my situation is quite complex, and more than one web applications are running in the same app domain, sharing user interface - Master Pages. Its allows creating web applications that inherits other web applications and provide custom implementation. Too big to get into details. 

What I am wondering though, is that @Page CompilerOptions might be useful somehow? If I use the /out compiler switch to give the compiled page assembly a name, I might be able to use InternalsVisibleTo attribute. However I can't dynamically specify the target folder for the /out.

Comment: I don't think that would work, as if you change the assembly name, ASP.NET would no longer know how to load it.

Still trying to understand the scenario.  Is this a Web Application or a Web Site?  Also, where exactly is that class that's getting compiled twice?  Is it in a .cs file in App_Code?  Or is it in the code behind of a page?  Would really need to understand the structure of the app to comment meaningfully.

Comment: It is a web application. The class being compiled twice is a code behind class of a control that we tried to share between two web applications. But because both of them lived in the same app_domain, the class become ambiguous. To summarize what we tried to do is - share UI between web apps that are different, but live in the same app_domain. Though we found a workaround to that, I still wonder what is the best technique for sharing UI? Because code behind class has to be public, its kind of impossible for two apps that share the same control to live together?

Comment: Note that from ASP.NET's point of view, an AppDomain only contains one app, so what you have is more like different areas of the same app. But they have no separation from each other. But about your issue, you should generally avoid ever compiling the same class in multiple assemblies. I'd suggest having that code behind exist only once in a shared assembly. Though again, missing lots of details about the structure of your app, so I can only try to guess.

Comment: That's basically how you share code, that is a compile unit. UI on other hand is not, unless precompiled. The only way to share UI is to have that UI in this control in the project using it. And this is how this problem emerges. In general we can summarize my question as how can one share UserControl between applications without precompiling the application that brings it.

Comment: When you have foo.ascx and foo.ascx.cs, the ascx ends up creating a class derived from the class in ascx.cs.  WHat I'm saying is that you should compile foo.ascx.cs (which is not UI) in a single assembly, but then have two copies of foo.ascx using it.  This should work without issues.